# SQL Server : nested stored procedure to update table values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table structure and its data as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
    id INT Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    creationTimestamp DATE,
    indexOne INT,
    indexTwo INT
);

INSERT INTO TestTable (creationTimestamp, indexOne, indexTwo) 
VALUES 
(2014-01-10, 100, 0),
(2014-01-11, 100, 0),
(2014-01-12, 100, 0),
(2014-01-13, 152, 2),
(2014-01-14, 152, 2),
(2014-01-15, 152, 2),
(2014-02-12, 152, 2),
(2014-02-13, 152, 2),
(2014-02-14, 333, 4),
(2014-02-15, 333, 4),
(2014-02-16, 333, 4),
(2014-03-10, 333, 4),
(2014-03-11, 333, 4),
(2014-03-12, 333, 4),
(2014-03-13, 333, 4),
(2014-03-14, 333, 4),
(2014-04-20, 500, 7),
(2014-04-21, 500, 7),
(2014-04-22, 500, 7),
(2014-04-23, 500, 7);
```

When you consider indexOne + indexTwo, there are duplicate rows. But I need them to be unique.

Therefore indexTwo must be properly indexed as follows

```
(2014-01-10, 100, 0),
(2014-01-11, 100, 1),
(2014-01-12, 100, 2),
(2014-01-13, 152, 0),
(2014-01-14, 152, 1),
(2014-01-15, 152, 2),
(2014-02-12, 152, 3),
(2014-02-13, 152, 4),
(2014-02-14, 333, 0),
(2014-02-15, 333, 1),
(2014-02-16, 333, 2),
(2014-03-10, 333, 3),
(2014-03-11, 333, 4),
(2014-03-12, 333, 5),
(2014-03-13, 333, 6),
(2014-03-14, 333, 7),
(2014-04-20, 500, 0),
(2014-04-21, 500, 1),
(2014-04-22, 500, 2),
(2014-04-23, 500, 3);
```

I have written the following stored procedure and it does not work properly

```
declare @indexOne int, @indexTwo int, @x int
declare c cursor for
select indexOne, indexTwo
from TestTable
group by indexOne, indexTwo 

open c
fetch next from c into @indexOne, @indexTwo
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @x = 0;             
    declare @id int

    declare c1 cursor for
    select id
    from TestTable
    where indexOne = @indexOne and indexTwo = @indexTwo
    order by creationTimestamp asc  

    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @id

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0                    
    begin
        UPDATE TestTable SET indexTwo = @x WHERE id = @id   
        set @x = @x + 1 
        fetch next from c1 into @id
    end

    close c1
    deallocate c1
    fetch next from c into @indexOne, @indexTwo

end
close c
deallocate c
```

Help me to find why this is not working

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is mysql syntax

Comment: Your table definition is MySQL syntax.  Your code is SQL Server syntax.  You should decide which database you are really using, tag your question appropriately, and write syntax appropriate for the database.  That will go a long way to fixing your syntax problems.

Comment: In my office I have MSSQL. I tried this at home on MySQL. that's why different syntaxs. sorry about it. But I need the stored procedure in MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `cursor` to do this use `window function` to generate the `indextwo` values per `creationtimestamp, indexone`. I hope this will do the job.

`Sql Server`

```
UPDATE A 
SET    indexTwo = b.indexTwo  
FROM   testtable a 
       JOIN (SELECT creationTimestamp, indexOne, 
                    Row_number()OVER(partition BY indexone 
                        ORDER BY creationtimestamp)-1 indexTwo  
             FROM   testtable) B 
         ON a.creationtimestamp = b.creationtimestamp 
            AND a.indexone = b.indexone
```

### [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88e742/2)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would really appreciate it, if you could explain this solution. I need the solution in MSSQL

Comment: @mb first run the select query alone. `Row_number` is going to generate `row number` for `each row`. Using `Partition` by we are generating row number inside each partition, `row number` will start from `1` for each partition since you need 1 in `indexTwo`  for least `creationtimestamp` i am using `order by creationtimestamp asc`.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!. But is it possible to modify this solution such that indexTwo starts from zero.

Comment: @mb - Updated to start from `0`. In partition by only `indexone` should be present i corrected it now.